# Core Results WebPart - Fetched Properties Error and FAST

Tags: 2010, search, fast-search, search-results

I'm having a weird problem I'm trying to understand and resolve.

I'm provisionning through a feature a custom search results page (and a page layout, master page, css file and xslt stylesheet).  When the core results webpart appears on the page, this error occurs :

"Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings."

As long as I am only using one instance of this webpart on the page, the errors is always shown.  But at the moment where I add a new core results webpart (the exact same as the one provisionned), the new one works, but the first one still doesn't work.  I can then put the first one in hidden mode and everything works.

What is happening ?

I tried to check with the default result page, and it does not happen with the OOTB page.

I am not using custom columns, so I don't understand why this error is the one shown.  The logs have absolutely nothing related to that...

Does anyone have an idea where is the problem ?

**EDIT :**

I tried not provisionning the webpart with the feature and only adding it through the user interface by uploading it, and it had the exact same behaviour.

**EDIT 2 :**

Here is my module content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="SiteFiles" Url="Pages" Path="SiteFiles">
    <File Url="Results.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <AllUsersWebPart WebPartOrder="0" WebPartZoneID="TopZone">
        <![CDATA[
          <webParts>
            <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
              <metaData>
                <type name="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
              </metaData>
              <data>
                <properties>
                  <property name="SpellcheckingMode" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SpellcheckMode, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Suggest</property>
                  <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
                  <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Modeless</property>
                  <property name="CharactersInUrl" type="int">90</property>
                  <property name="ShowLangPicker" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="DisplayName" type="string" />
                  <property name="MoreLinkUrl" type="string" null="true" />
                  <property name="Title" type="string">Search Core Results</property>
                  <property name="ShowActionLinks" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="ViewFlag" type="string">0</property>
                  <property name="QueryNumber" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.QueryId, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Query1</property>
                  <property name="PreviewWindowSize" type="string">160</property>
                  <property name="DateFormat" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPDateFormat, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">DateOnly</property>
                  <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="SentencesInSummary" type="System.Int16, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">3</property>
                  <property name="HighestResultPage" type="System.Int16, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">1000</property>
                  <property name="CacheXslTimeOut" type="int">86400</property>
                  <property name="RelevanceView" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="MoreLinkLabel" type="string">View more results »</property>
                  <property name="ManualRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="ListUrl" type="string" null="true" />
                  <property name="FixedQuery" type="string" />
                  <property name="CacheXslStorage" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="ResubmitFlag" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ResubmitFlag, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">NoResubmit</property>
                  <property name="XslLink" type="string" null="true" />
                  <property name="EnableStemming" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="ShowSearchResults" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="ShowMoreLink" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="ListDisplayName" type="string" null="true" />
                  <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
                  <property name="EnableDocumentPreviewPowerPoint" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="DefaultRankingModelID" type="string" />
                  <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string" />
                  <property name="Default" type="string" />
                  <property name="DisplayRSSLink" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="FireInitialRow" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="TotalNumberDocumentPreview" type="string">10</property>
                  <property name="DateView" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="ViewFlags" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewFlags, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">None</property>
                  <property name="DisplayAlertMeLink" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="DataSourceID" type="string" />
                  <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
                  <property name="DisplayDiscoveredDefinition" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="AppendedQuery" type="string" />
                  <property name="AsyncRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="IgnoreNoise" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="Height" type="string" />
                  <property name="PageSize" type="int">-1</property>
                  <property name="UseSQLDataSourcePaging" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="ViewContentTypeId" type="string" />
                  <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="DefaultSort" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ResultsView, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Relevance</property>
                  <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
                  <property name="ConcurrentNumberDocumentPreview" type="string">10</property>
                  <property name="ListName" type="string" />
                  <property name="PropertiesToRetrieve" type="string">&lt;Columns&gt;  &lt;Column Name="WorkId"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Rank"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Title"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Author"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Size"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Path"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Description"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Write"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="SiteName"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="CollapsingStatus"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="HitHighlightedSummary"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="HitHighlightedProperties"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="ContentClass"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="IsDocument"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="PictureThumbnailURL"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="PopularSocialTags"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="PictureWidth"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="PictureHeight"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="DatePictureTaken"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="ServerRedirectedURL"/&gt;  &lt;/Columns&gt;</property>
                  <property name="ParameterBindings" type="string" null="true" />
                  <property name="DataSourcesString" type="string" />
                  <property name="EnablePhonetic" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="ListId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</property>
                  <property name="Scope" type="string" />
                  <property name="XmlDefinitionLink" type="string" />
                  <property name="DataFields" type="string" />
                  <property name="ShowMessages" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="Width" type="string" />
                  <property name="InitialAsyncDataFetch" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="QuerySideLanguage" type="string">-1</property>
                  <property name="MoreResultsLink" type="string" null="true" />
                  <property name="XmlDefinition" type="string" />
                  <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
                  <property name="PageType" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.PAGETYPE, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">PAGE_NORMALVIEW</property>
                  <property name="ScopeID" type="int">1</property>
                  <property name="SelectColumns" type="string">&lt;Columns&gt;  &lt;Column Name="WorkId"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Rank"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Title"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Author"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Size"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Path"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Description"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="Write"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="SiteName"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="CollapsingStatus"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="HitHighlightedSummary"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="HitHighlightedProperties"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="ContentClass"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="IsDocument"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="PictureThumbnailURL"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="PopularSocialTags"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="PictureWidth"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="PictureHeight"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="DatePictureTaken"/&gt;  &lt;Column Name="ServerRedirectedURL"/&gt;  &lt;/Columns&gt;</property>
                  <property name="SampleData" type="string">&lt;All_Results&gt;  &lt;Result&gt;    &lt;workid&gt;1&lt;/workid&gt;    &lt;rank&gt;222&lt;/rank&gt;    &lt;title&gt;Title of document or web page&lt;/title&gt;    &lt;author&gt;Author of document or web page&lt;/author&gt;    &lt;size&gt;1025&lt;/size&gt;    &lt;sitename&gt;http://www.sample.com&lt;/sitename&gt;    &lt;url&gt;http://www.sample.com/folder/document.aspx&lt;/url&gt;    &lt;imageurl&gt;/_layouts/images/aspx16.gif&lt;/imageurl&gt;    &lt;description&gt;This is the summary of the document or web page. The summary is generated from the original document based on matches with query terms. In some cases, the summary is a description provided by the author.&lt;/description&gt;    &lt;write&gt;December 26, 2004&lt;/write&gt;  &lt;/Result&gt;&lt;/All_Results&gt;</property>
                  <property name="EnableDocumentPreviewWord" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="AutoRefreshInterval" type="int">60</property>
                  <property name="CharactersInSummary" type="int">185</property>
                  <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
                  <property name="RemoveDuplicates" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="Xsl" type="string" />
                  <property name="View" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ResultsView, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Relevance</property>
                  <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
                  <property name="EnableSimilarFind" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
                  <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="ResultsPerPage" type="System.Int16, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">10</property>
                  <property name="ShowWithSampleData" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="Description" type="string">Displays the search results and the properties associated with them.</property>
                  <property name="EnableNicknames" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="AutoRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="IsLocationPeople" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="Location" type="string">LocalSearchIndex</property>
                  <property name="NoDefaultStyle" type="string" null="true" />
                  <property name="ShowWindowsSearch" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="UseLocationVisualization" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="MoreResultsText" type="string">View more results »</property>
                </properties>
              </data>
            </webPart>
          </webParts>
        ]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart>
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you adding the Core Search Results onto the page? I wonder if you populated the "Selected Columns" property, if it is being left blank or has invalid data.

Comment: I'm adding it through a module with <AllUserWebPart>.  The columns are present and they do not seem to have any invalid data.

Comment: I finally found the problem. I had another webpart on the page (Refinement Panel) that was sending invalid columns to the search results. It appears that the Refinement Panel can only affect the first search results webpart on the page, the reason why the first was never working, the second always.

Answer (score 0):

Please export both webpart definitions (or use the provisioned one and export the working one) and compare them with winmerge. I bet there is some difference in it.

Comment: I checked, they are exactly the same.  That is the weird part of it.

Comment: what location ID (order?) are you assigning the webpart? 0 or 1?

Comment: I'm assigning 1... Will try with 0.

Comment: The WebPartOrder did not change the weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try using only the properties that you need to set. If you export the web part, you get all properties assigned to the web part - even the default values.
I have defined only following properties in my web part and it works quite well:

```
<property name="Title" type="string">$Resources:Microsoft.Office.Server.Search,SearchActionsWP_Title;</property>
<property name="Description" type="string">$Resources:Microsoft.Office.Server.Search,SearchActionsWP_Desc;</property>
<property name="ChromeType">None</property>
<property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">true</property>
<property name="AllowClose" type="bool">true</property> 
<property name="Hidden" type="bool">false</property>
<property name="ShowMessages" type="bool">false</property>
<property name="ShowSearchResults" type="bool">false</property>
<property name="uselocationvisualization" type="bool">false</property>
<property name="Location" type="string">LocalSearchIndex</property>
```

Comment: I tried and I still have the same behaviour.  I will try in another environment.